# Looking for a powershell script that can pull a file from a set of PC's and FTP

Tags: networking, powershell, ftp, scripting

I'm looking to write a script (preferably powershell) that will essentially copy a file from a bunch of PC's and FTP it to a server.

So the structure of the environment is that we have a file on multiple PC's (around 50 or so) that need to placed on a server. Sometimes one of the PC's may be turned off so the script would first need to ensure the PC is up and running (maybe a ping result), then it would need to go into a directory on that PC, pull a file off of it, rename the file, place into a source directory, then remove the file. Naming convention doesn't matter, but date/time stamp would be easiest. Ideally, it would be best to first move all the files to a source directory to save on FTP bandwidth, but since the files will be named the same, the files must be renamed during the move process. Move not copy because the directory needs to be empty so the file can be re-created the next day. So once moved to the source directory, now all the files need to be FTP'd to a server for processing.

After all of this, we need to know which PC's on the list did not respond so we can manually retrieve the file so the script should output a file (txt is fine) that will show which PC's were offline.

Everything is one domain and script will be run from an server with admin creds.

Thank you!

Comment: So what have you written? What is/isn't working?  Any error messages?

Comment: @jscott I haven't written anything just yet, I am in the planning phase and looking for ideas on the best route to take with this. I'm not an "advanced" powershell user and could def use some help starting this off. Thanks again!

Comment: What you ask is, i think, not the philosophy of this site. First write/try something and you will be welcome when you are stuck, with a more precise question regarding a specific problem...

Comment: @krisFR I appreciate the feedback.. I can throw up some FTP scripts or some file/copy scripts easily, those are not the issue. The issue I am having is combining everything into the way I need. So if you would prefer I ask my question a different way, I can certainly do so... but I was under the impression the site was for asking direct questions that needed answers, which is what I am asking here. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I am actually writing a sample script for you, what is you main problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited :

```
$down = "C:\Script\log\down-hosts.log"
$nofile = "C:\Script\log\no-file.log"
$computers = Get-Content "C:\Script\list\Computers.txt"
$TargetPath = "\\server\directory\directory\"
$SourceFileName = "file_name.csv"
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
  if ( Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
{
    $sourcefilePath = "\\$computer\c$\UPS CSV Exports\$SourceFileName"
    Write-Host "$computer is up"
    Write-Host "Copying $SourceFilePath ..."
    Try {
      If (Test-Path $SourceFilePath) {
         Move-Item $SourceFilePath "$TargetPath\$computer`_$SourceFileName" -force
      } Else {
        #Throw "$SourceFilePath does not exist"
        Write-Host "$computer file does not exist"
        "$computer $SourceFileName file does not exist" | Out-File $nofile -append
      }
    } Catch {
       Write-Host "Error: $($Error[0].Exception.Message)"
    }
  } Else {
    Write-Host "$computer is down"
    "$computer is down $(get-date)" | Out-File $down -append 
  }
}
```

Some new explanations :

- Use of `Test-Connection` to test if host is up (no ping). - Kept this as it worked well
- Use of `New-Item` not necessary.
- Use of `Move-Item` instead of FTP protocol.
- Added new log features: `"$computer $SourceFileName file does not exist" | Out-File $nofile -append` which offers a second log showing the file did not exist.
- Added new log feature: `"$computer is down $(get-date)" | Out-File $down -append` which shows the computer is down but also stamps it with a date/time.

Comment: I am taking a look at this now... I will reply with feedback shortly, but I appreciate the head start. It looks good, I may have a few questions.. Correct me if I am wrong, are you simply FTP'ing the file directly from the source to the FTP server? I don't see a move or copy file.. am I reading this correctly? My reason for the help as per your previous question was that Im a novice with PS and am learning... at my job we have a need and I know it can be done with PS I just lack the advanced knowledge of getting it done. So I do appreciate your assistance.

Comment: There is no move or copy. I don't understand why you want this. The file is copied to FTP server with the client hostname as prefix. Why do you need a move/copy ? This is not clear for me and could not be required. explain.

Comment: I agree, the way you wrote it I just realized removes the file so I don't think a move/copy is necessary. I was only thinking to move/copy the file to a directory then FTP'in that directory so we only need to FTP one time instead of 50 times, but it doesn't really matter. Make sense?

Comment: It depends : if you have one file per client to copy into the FTP it does not make sense, for multiple files per client it could...But in this case the real gain would be to ZIP files on client side before sending the ZIP onto the FTP

Comment: ...or we could consider that nevermind if a client has one or more file to transfer. We could tranfer all clients' files into a temp centralized directory, then ZIP this, and send the ZIP to the FTP in one shot. For sure this is a gain : 1 FTP transfert instead of 50 : is it what you want ?

Comment: That was the idea yes, one FTP instead of 50 yes. So all files would be copied/moved to a central location (could be on the same box running the script) then FTP'd to the server specified.

Comment: The source file is located on the network on other computers. The location to the file will be the same for all of them. So for example, C:\Directory\Directory\file.csv - the script should pull this file from all the computers in the list but will be the same spot for everyone.

Comment: So you have everything here in my sample code to get you started.

Comment: when testing the script, I am getting an error: Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."

Comment: I re-wrote the script and edited your post, to use a move command instead of the FTP as it was causing some issues working. Since the server is on the same domain as the one running the script, it was easier to go this route instead of the FTP route. I also added in some additional logging. \

Comment: Ok, no problem. Cheers !